# How to set the body for a Simple.OData.Client create entry request using C#?

Tags: c#, simple.odata.client

Creating an entry using `Simple.OData.Client` I need to use the method `InsertEntryAsync()`. Correct?

The body of the `oData` request contains the insert data in Json format, but where do I have to set the body for such a call?

My coding looks like this:

```
using Simple.OData.Client;

var client = new ODataClient(
    new ODataClientSettings
    {
        BaseUri = baseUri,
        Credentials = credentials,
        OnTrace = OnTraceHandler,
    });

var headers = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>
{
    { "Accept-Language", new string[] { "de-DE" } },
    { "Accept", new string[] { "application/json" } },
    { "X-CSRF-TOKEN", new string[] { Class1.x_scrf_token } }
};
client.UpdateRequestHeaders(headers);

var dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
string body = "{\"name\":\"John\", \"city\":\"New York\"}";

var entryInsert = await client.InsertEntryAsync("PeopleSet", dict);
```

Comment: What's your return? An exception is thrown?

Comment: See my coding, the variable string body is never set to the oData call. My question is, how to set this value as "input parameter".

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution myself.
Instead of attaching a Json as body, I need to set the values to the dictionary like

dict.Add("name", "John");
dict.Add("city", "New York");

and use the dict as second parameter of InsertEntryAsync("PeopleSet", dict).